# Como consumir https json con webform asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy queriendo consumir un servicio **HTTPS** . Realizando con asp.net webform.
Por la cual estoy realizando con jquery json he estado leyendo la documentación y indica que se tiene que usar JSONP.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

lo que quiero es extraer los datos que me arroja ese json y colocarla en un input.

Esta es la información que me arroja y quisiera extraer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por la cual he utilizado este es mi codigo.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function getProducts() {
            var url = "https://www.sentinelconsultagratuita.com/wsrest/Rest/Rws_evalcredit?Usuario=********&Password=********&Servicio=188714&TipoDoc=D&NroDoc=43400262"
             $.getJSON(url, {
                tags: "mount rainier",
                tagmode: "any",
                format: "jsonp"
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                    $('#products').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                        var row = '<td>' + val.Resultado + '</td><td>' + val.Resultado + '</td>';
                        $('<tr/>', { html: row })
                            .appendTo($('#products'));
                    });
                  });

        }

        $(document).ready(getProducts);
</script>
```

Me sale un error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizando Libreris Restshar.

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://www.sentinelconsultagratuita.com/wsrest/Rest/Rws_evalcredit");
  var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("Usuario", "*********"); 
            request.AddParameter("Password", "********");
            request.AddParameter("Servicio", "188714");
            request.AddParameter("TipoDoc", "D");
            request.AddParameter("NroDoc", "43400262");
  IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
 var content = response.Content; 
 TextBox1.Text = response.Content;
```

me sale en blanco lo que quiero extraer en mi texbox1

Comment: La consulta la debes hacer desde el servidor, en C#. Puedes usar la librería "RestSharp" para realizar las peticiones.

Comment: @fredyfx gracias hermano , leere la documentación de esa libreria nuget para hacerlo :)

Comment: de nada hermano, aprendes rápido :)

Comment: @fredyfx esta bien lo que realize con RestSharp

Comment: ¿Tienes brekpoints que te indiquen si el request fue ejecutado? De ser así, ¿Qué retorna?

Comment: @fredyfx si me sale en blanco o sera porque no tengo acceso a esa pagina por que me vota en blanco pero solo quisiera saber si esta bien la estructura como se envia y retorna el valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí la solución, OJO, antes de aplicar la respuesta ponte a debuggear un rato para que veas por qué no te sale con el código que tienes, mira si el EndPoint es correcto, mira si el servidor da error y haz la pregunta clave "¿Por qué?".

Te dejo de tarea investigar la diferencia entre: `AddBody` y `AddParameter`.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.sentinelconsultagratuita.com/wsrest/Rest/Rws_evalcredit");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new {
    Usuario = "******",
    Password = "*****",
    Servicio = 188714,
    TipoDoc = "D",
    NroDoc = 43400262
});

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
TextBox1.Text = response.Content;
```

Un abrazo hermano, vas por buen camino :)